# MS SQL, рекурсивный запрос.

Tags: sql-server

Не силен в рекурсивных запросах, поэтому был бы признателен,если бы помогли с вот такой задачей : есть таблица Chair(Кафедра) и её структура :  `ID | Name | IsActive | HistLink` . 
При изменении имени кафедры проиcходит  следующее : у старой кафедры поле IsActive c 1 меняется на 0 , и затем добавляется(именно добавляется) кафедра с новым именем и указанием в поле HistLink ID старой кафедры.Например :

```
ID | Name            | IsActive  | HistLink
 3 | Старое_название | 0(была 1) | null
 5 | Новое_название  | 1         | 3
```

И нужно как-то 1-им запросом, зная ID старой кафедры, определить текущую(активную)(И конечно название меняться может > 1 раза).Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with cte as 
(select Id, Name from chair, 0 as lvl
 where ID = 3 --Идентификатор первого значение в рекурсивном дереве
 union all
 select chair.id, chair.name, cte.lvl + 1 as lvl 
   from chair
        inner join cte --рекурсивный джойн
                on chair.HistLink = cte.ID)
select top 1 id, Name --выбираем единственную запись
  from cte
  order by lvl desc -- которая является самой последней в "дереве" переименований
```

Comment: Спасибо,только вот меня смущает chair.HistLink = cte.ID . У меня ведь не старая кафедра(поле HistLink) ссылается на новую , а наоборот , измененная ссылается на старую . Пробовал просто поменять chair.ID = cte.HistLink , но что-то ругается на cte .

Comment: А вы запрос то пробовали выполнять? Смысл в чем - вы получаете первую строку дерева: id=3. На втором шаге присоединяете к ней все ее дочки HistLink=3 (3 - это id из первой строки - из уже сформированной таблицы cte, поэтому cte.id). На третьем шаге примоединяете дочки второго уровня.... В конце выбираете первую запись из таблицы, сортированной по убыванию номера уровня, т.е выбираете последнюю запись.

Comment: Точно,спасибо.